# Somebody downvoting all answers to a question?

Tags: discussion

There have been three almost identical answers on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39740931/when-this-code-is-run-it-display-5-3-1-why-does-c-1), which all seem to answer the question, but they have all been downvoted by 1.

Is somebody down-voting answers because they don't like the question?  It's not a *great* question, but it seems reasonable enough to me (although it is currently -5).

Should I flag it for moderator attention?  Should I ignore it?

Full disclosure: One of the answers is mine.

Comment: A moderator won't do anything about this. People are allowed to roll dice and downvote based on the result, if they wanted to do so.

Comment: I personally down-vote all answers to poor questions. The proper way to deal with poor questions is to discourage the poster by closing/deletion, not add positive confirmation by posting an answer. Answers are supposed to be judged individually of course, but I have chosen to exercise my free will regarding my cast votes in a manner that discourages answering poor questions.

Comment: @SeinopSys: I understand.  As I said, I don't think this is a particularly poor question (although others seem to disagree).  I'm also not convinced that I agree with your approach (although I understand the approach).  Incidentally, do you want to make that an answer?

Comment: @MartinBonner I don't feel that my personal practices would provide a definitive answer to your questions, that's why I left a comment instead.

Comment: @SeinopSys - I always find it amusing to hear users say that when speaking in broad terms, but when you look at their recent history, they don't actually do that in practice. For example, this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/35363250/1026459 ... or this one http://stackoverflow.com/q/37735022/1026459 both of which you answered. Personally, I would *stop* downvoting other answers solely based on question quality because that is *not* how it is supposed to work, and is not even the approach you are actually using.

Comment: @TravisJ Yes, there are some exceptions where I don't. In any case, what I wanted to describe was a possible reason why I _would have_ down-voted all answers to the question in question, and I indeed did not make it clear that this is not how I handle these situations every time. My apologies. I continue to reserve the right to cast my votes in the manner I see fit, however.

Answer (score 19):

> Is somebody down-voting answers because they don't like the question?

You can't possibly know this.  All you know is somewhere between 1 and 3 people (you don't know it was one person) felt that those three answers weren't useful.  We could possibly guess, or indicate whether *we* feel a given answer is useful, but nobody but the voter(s) can know why, specifically, they voted.

> Should I flag it for moderator attention?

No.  Other people are allowed to vote on answers.  There's nothing for a moderator to do here. Even if it is one person who voted on the three answers, that person is allowed to feel that these three answers aren't helpful.  And given that you've asserted that the three answers are very similar, it would stand to reason that if someone felt one of them isn't helpful, the others plausibly wouldn't be as well, and would also merit a similar vote.

> Should I ignore it?

No.  Someone felt that an answer of yours wasn't helpful.  This is valuable feedback for you.  Consider it, reflect on it, and see if you can improve your answer as a result.

If none of the answers was yours, this is also useful information to you and shouldn't be ignored.  It tells you that those other answers are likely to not be useful, so if you're considering using them you should be wary of them and scrutinize them more than you otherwise might.

Comment: I can't possibly know: but at least SeinopSys has said he does exactly this.

Comment: @MartinBonner He said how he would have voted.  That doesn't actually tell you anything about how the person that voted chose to vote.

Comment: "*Should I ignore it?* No. Someone felt that an answer of yours wasn't helpful. This is valuable feedback for you." Hmm, I think you're wrong. Some people are haters or the question is too easy for them (like some of mine: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35370727/parse-javascript-variable-declarations or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38817819/how-to-make-element-non-static-in-class-in-c)... *Should I ignore it?* Anyone can answer that - I would ignore it. Stackoverflow is there for explaining things, isn't it?

Comment: Those aren't haters @SzymonMarczak. Stick to that approach and you'll never improve.

Comment: @SzymonMarczak If you never accept any negative feedback from anyone else, and always take it as an assumption that you are always right and everyone saying anything you don't like is wrong, then that's going to cause you *major* problems.  It'll inhibit your ability to grow and learn, it prevents you from learning from your mistakes (resulting in you repeating them) it will *greatly* limit the people you'll be able to effectively interact with, etc.  Particularly in a field such as programming, if you refuse to ever acknowledge even the *possibility* of having been wrong it'll limit you.

Comment: @Servy I don't say I'm always right. Some people downvote because the question looks stupid. Some of them don't even comment the question - so you don't know what's wrong. I think we should explain why it's like this, and not like that...

Comment: The downvote tooltip provides an indication. Beyond that, no user is obliged to leave any further comments.

Comment: @SzymonMarczak You said you should always ignore downvotes because people are haters.  To assume that nobody could ever possibly be correct in their criticism of your answer is to assert that you're always right (by saying you're never wrong).

Comment: @Bart I know, but sometimes we have to guess the reason why someone downvoted the question.

Comment: @Servy I did **not** say I should always ignore downvotes because people are haters (could you quote me?). You said you always accept downvotes. I said, that I would ignore [some] downvotes, because I think the question is clear. Someone thinks the question isn't clear. I don't know why he thinks the question isn't clear. Each answer should be useful for the author of the question.

Comment: @Servy I think people should explain their choice, and help with improving questions and answers.

Comment: @SzymonMarczak I said you should never ignore downvotes.  You should always consider the feedback.  After careful consideration, you may feel that you answer is as good as you can make it, or not find any way of improving it, but that is not ignoring the feedback, that's simply not acting on it after carefully considering it.  When you say that the feedback shouldn't even be *considered*, and saying that you should ignore it out of hand, there isn't even any way of selectively applying it based on merit.

Comment: @SzymonMarczak And it's been shown, almost literally every day of meta's existence, that that is a net harmful behavior, for a very large list of reasons that you can trivially look up if you're interested.  There are times where such comments can be helpful, and people are certainly welcome to provide them in such situations, but they are not nearly as helpful as you seem to believe, and the practice of requiring them would result in them being *extremely* harmful.

Comment: @Servy You're right. I always consider the feedback. I appreciate it very much. I don't ignore all downvotes. I don't ignore it at all. By ignoring I mean I don't understand their vote, so after a while I stop considering why he downvoted. Simply answer: I don't know.

Comment: @Servy I don't downvote dumb questions (except if it's as easy as 2+2). Some people don't understand why it's like this, and not like that. I think we should we explain it...

Comment: @SzymonMarczak What does that have to do with this quesiton at all?

Comment: @Servy This is my personal opinion.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124436/discussion-between-szymon-marczak-and-servy).

Answer (score 6):

Despite not being able to see deleted stuff, I can reasonably assume that the answers were given by three different people.

Because of this, it is valid for a single person to down vote all the answers. It is not serial down voting, and a moderator wouldn't do anything if they could (I don't think they have the ability to reverse individual votes, anyway).

You might be able to assume that a single person down voted them all if the votes all happened within a certain timeframe, but it's not a guarantee (especially on a large site like this.)

---

I'm sure there is a reason why the answers were down voted, regardless if it was one person or not. The fact that the question is now deleted (manually deleted, as @[Josh](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/603977/josh-caswell)'s [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/exuYf.png) confirms), indicates the question was rather poor, and it was off topic (unclear what you're asking).

You should avoid answering off topic questions for several reasons. Answers to off topic questions may be down voted and deleted (usually with the question). It doesn't reflect well on you, especially as an "experienced user" to be answering these questions. The presence of answers, additionally, interferes with deletion in some cases.

Comment: I suspect the question has been deleted by the poster because of the down-votes.  As I said, I felt the question was a reasonable one (even if others didn't).

Comment: @MartinBonner That's also a possibility. Did you try to edit the question? Sometimes, the only problem with a question is its horrible presentation.

Comment: For those who can't see it, the question was deleted by three >20k users, two of whom had also voted to close the question: http://i.stack.imgur.com/exuYf.png @MartinBonner